# How do I interpret "waitpid function doesn't wait for the child that terminates first;"?

Tags: unix

In the Book "Advanced Programming in Unix Environment", section [wait and waitpid](https://books.google.com/books?id=kCTMFpEcIOwC&pg=PA238&lpg=PA238&dq=waitpid+doesn%27t+wait+for+the+child+that+terminates+first&source=bl&ots=zwLz_J_xjI&sig=ACfU3U1i8jDvW5CQQHlDmOXv9wicyG20LQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjKyLSVma_oAhUXhXIEHVJ_Ap0Q6AEwCnoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=waitpid%20doesn't%20wait%20for%20the%20child%20that%20terminates%20first&f=false) says:

> waitpid function doesn't wait for the child that terminates first; it has a number of options that control which process it waits for.

I was reading this as if the child process exit first and the parent process hasn't called the `waitpid` function, the child process won't be waited and will stay as a zombie process after quit.

So I wrote some code to test:

```
int main() {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        // child process
        printf("Child Process ID: %d \n", getpid());
        printf("Child Process Quit\n");
        exit(0);
    } else {
        // parent 
        sleep(5);
        printf("Parent Process ID: %d \n", getpid());
        printf("Wait child %d ...\n", pid);
        int status;
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        printf("waitpid called\n");
        sleep(5);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program first print out "Child Process ID" and "Child Process Quit", while the parent process is still sleeping, in another terminal window, if I use `ps -el | grep 'Z'`, I am able to see this child process is `<defunct>` (zombie).

Then 5 seconds later, as long as the parent process called `waitpid`, in another terminal window, use `ps -el | grep 'Z'` won't show the zombie child process any more, so it means the child process has been waited and not a zombie any more.

So seems the parent process can always wait for a child process with `waitpid`, so how do I interpret this "waitpid function doesn't wait for the child that terminates first"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you complete the quotation (as it is now completed in the question), you see that [`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html) is more flexible (than `wait()`).

The POSIX specification says:

> The *pid* argument specifies a set of child processes for which status is requested. The `waitpid()` function shall only return the status of a child process from this set:
>
> - If *pid* is equal to `(pid_t)-1`, status is requested for any child process. In this respect, `waitpid()` is then equivalent to `wait()`.
> - If *pid* is greater than 0, it specifies the process ID of a single child process for which status is requested.
> - If *pid* is 0, status is requested for any child process whose process group ID is equal to that of the calling process.
> - If *pid* is less than `(pid_t)-1`, status is requested for any child process whose process group ID is equal to the absolute value of *pid*.

So, as the quote says, `waitpid()` doesn't always (only) wait for the first child to die; you can select much more precisely which child or children you are interested in.  Additionally, you have options like `WNOHANG` that mean that the function returns if there is no child that has died that meets the criterion (but there's at least one process that would meet the criterion).  You get a different status if there are no children that meet the criteria.

Comment: Ah, I see, if it actually is "waitpid function doesn't (only) wait for the child that terminates first", then it makes perfect sense. I am confused b/c without the word "only", its meaning is totally different. Thank you Jonathan!